# Monotone convergence for Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

Is there some monotone convergence theorem to prove that: if $f_n \uparrow f$ with $f_n$ positive and continuous, and $g\in BV([a, b])$, then 
$$\int_a^b f_n dg \longrightarrow \int_a^b f dg \quad ?$$

Comment: Not unless $g$ is positive.

Comment: In the case where $g$ is positive there exists? Do you have some reference?

Comment: Sorry... I meant increasing. Basically: It's not true unless $dg$ corresponds to integration with respect to a positive measure.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm also interested on applying dominated convergence. Is there some references?

Comment: $dg$ is just a signed measure so dominated convergence works fine. I.e. if $h\in L^1(|dg|)$ and $|f_n|\leq h$ such that $f_n\to f$ $|dg|$-a.e., then $\int_a^b f_n \textrm{d}g\to \int_a^b f\textrm{d}g$